DeepAR LSTM using dynamic features to forecast?
I'm using gluonts.torch implementation of DeepAR to forecast a future sale using search volume as a dependent/input/dynamic variable.
my data look like this:
Date        Sale Search
2018-12-30  205 13
2019-01-06  245 19
2019-01-13  207 20
2019-01-20  221 21
2019-01-27  179 17
... ... ...
2023-11-26  142 11
2023-12-03  183 13
2023-12-10  211 14
2023-12-17  236 14
2023-12-24  275 15

I did the following:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from gluonts.dataset.pandas import PandasDataset
from gluonts.torch import DeepAREstimator
from gluonts.evaluation import make_evaluation_predictions, Evaluator

#read in data
sales = pd.read_csv('data/sales.csv',index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

#split train and test
prediction_length=52
to_pandasdataset = lambda data: PandasDataset(
    data,target="Sale",
    feat_dynamic_real=["Search"]
)
train = to_pandasdataset(sales.iloc[:-prediction_length,:])
test = to_pandasdataset(sales)

#train and predict
estimator = DeepAREstimator(freq="1W", prediction_length=prediction_length, num_layers=4, num_feat_dynamic_real=1[![enter image description here][1]][1],hidden_size=14,trainer_kwargs={'accelerator': 'cpu', 'max_epochs':10})

predictor = estimator.train(train,num_workers=8)
forecast_it, ts_it = make_evaluation_predictions(dataset=test, predictor=predictor)
forecasts = list(forecast_it)
tests = list(ts_it)
evaluator = Evaluator(quantiles=(np.arange(20) / 20.0)[1:])
agg_metrics, item_metrics = evaluator(tests, forecasts, num_series=len(test))

#plot

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(12, 6))
#ax.plot(tests[0][-10 * prediction_length :].to_timestamp())
ax.plot(tests[0].to_timestamp())
plt.sca(ax)
forecasts[0].plot(intervals=(0.9,))

# add a vertical line at the end of the training period

last_training_date = sales.index[-prediction_length]
plt.axvline(x=last_training_date, color='red', linestyle='--')

plt.legend(["observed", "predicted median", "90% prediction interval","Training End"])
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("")
plt.show()

The prediction seems very bad:

The reason I think it is bad is because the correlation between the sale and search is really high:

Am I missing something while training or the model didn't take in the dynamic feature values when testing/predicting? How come it performs this bad? With this high correlation, a simple linear regression would easily outperform the deepAR, right?
